# Node TCP socket: connect event fired when timeout event fired

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a little TCP application. When the app starts up, I try to connect to a remote server. If that connection is not successful within a couple seconds, I want to catch that, throw an error, and then start the process over again.

Here is my basic code for the connection.

```
var connected = false;
var socket = new net.Socket();
socket.setTimeout(2000, function () {
  console.log('timeout');
  console.log(connected);
  if (connected) return;

  // retry
});
socket.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});
socket.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('connected');
  connected = true;
});
socket.connect(port, host);
```

The variables port and host refer to a host that exists but is not listening on the specified port.

When I try this locally, after 2 seconds I see the `timeout` message printed to the console. When I try it in production, I see BOTH the `connect` and `timeout` messages printed to the console, with the `connect` message printed first. If I change the timeout to 5 seconds, or 10 seconds, or whatever, the same thing happens. Nothing is printed until the timeout is reached, then the `connect` message and `timeout` message show up at virtually the same time, but always with `connect` first.

I even logged the connected variable in the `timeout` handler and sure enough, it's set to `true`.

First of all, I can't figure out what would be making the `connect` event fire first. It's clearly not connecting because the message doesn't print until the timeout is reached, no matter what the timeout is.

Second of all, if the connection IS successful, then the timeout shouldn't be hit until 2 seconds later (or however long the timeout is set for).

Any ideas? Could it be something with the specific server setup? I'm totally lost.

### Edit

Note that this is not related to socket.io. I'm using node's net module.

### Solution

Figured this out by working with our hosting company. There were two things happening.

1. The connection was actually being established due to some setup on their side we were unaware of.
2. We were printing out some logs using `process.stout.write` rather than `console.log`. `process.stout.write` does not have a line return added, and the logging system used in our production environment does not register new logs until it sees a line return.

The combination of these two things was causing us to see the logs at weird times for things we weren't expecting. Problem solved.

Comment: But surely the answer is the same? the timeout doesn't work in the way you expect?

Comment: Does't really seem like a duplicate (at least not related to the one @EJP marked.) One quick comment... your syntax for setTimeout is reversed. Should be: `setTimeout(function,milliseconds,param1,param2,...)`

Comment: This is the socket.setTimeout function, not javascript's native setTimeout function. https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback